# Read contents of .edb file

Tags: .net, exchange-server

I was just curious to know if there is any way to read the content of a .edb file. 
I mean to say that I was thinking on the terms where in I can code to move the content of a .edb file to either .pst or .ost format. 
I am not looking for a tool. infact I want to make something of my own.
I need to work on .net.
Please suggest where to start.
any links any API any script would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has not provided any API's for reading offline EDB files. Here are links to help you get started [API Spec by Joachim Metz](http://code.google.com/p/libesedb/downloads/detail?name=Extensible%20Storage%20Engine%20%28ESE%29%20Database%20File%20%28EDB%29%20format.pdf)

[EDB File Structure](http://www.edbsearch.com/edb.html)

Good Luck!